# git merging a branch but not able to see the commit on the server

Tags: git

I created a development branch, called dev, which was based off "base", i.e. initially HEAD of dev was at HEAD of base.

I did some work in dev, tested and now wanted to merge dev to base. So, I checked out base and ran git merge dev. This merged my changes, basically did a fast-forward merge as no other commits went in during this period.

I ran git commit -a -m "comment" to commit the changes. The output is:

```
# On branch base
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/base' by 702 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

When I ran git push, I see:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To me@git.xzy.com:/git/xyz-tools.git
   fa0e506..e72ca98  base -> base
```

The HEAD does look like to be moved but when I see the server, this commit is not updated on it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct remote branch?

Comment: Yes, The base branch seems to be at the point when the dev branch was pulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ensure that you are tracking correctly with

```
cat .git/config
```

then explicitly push that branch with

```
git push origin base
```

Comment: I re-did the merge with explicit git push origin base and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do `git log base` on the remote / server. You might be looking at a wrong branch.